# Is that right to say "For the first time we show..."

Tags: phrases, prepositions

In a PhD thesis, I would like to express that I am the first one who has proved the result. Is it right to say "For the first time we show..."?

Comment: Grammatically speaking, it is correct, may only need a comma after *first time*. However, in your context, the sentence will not convey the meaning that you want to. It can mean that *you* did not prove earlier, not that no one has proved earlier.

Comment: yes, this is also my feeling. That is why I am asking how to express my meaning. Thanks!

Comment: "This work differs from any other published work, in that ..."

Comment: If you are the first ones to show something, *say just that*. "We are the first ones to show..."

Answer (score 1):

In a paper with multiple authors I would say that this is correct (and almost the only time you would use the active voice), but I just can't see it for a solo work - one author logically fits with **I** show.

You can always keep to the passive voice ("It is shown for the first time in this work that...").
Also is it the first time - if you have published this result before writing up, you may want to say that ("It was shown for the first time [me *et al.* 2013] that...")

Comment: That ambiguity remains, though. (re my comment at OP)

Comment: @Kris true enough, the usage is common though, as the alternative meaning is not all that helpful (instead you might use *It was shown in chapter 2 that...", and possibly introduce the first use with "An important result, which will be used later...")

Answer (score 0):

I suggest : "... we were able to show ...", unpretentious for all the others who missed : it suggests not that they were more or less incompetent, but unfortunately not in a position to ..., and that you were fortunate enough to ...